# How to merge both audio channels into left channel?

Tags: 12.04, sound

My headset broke recently and now only left side of it works. In some songs, there are parts that are only played through the right side and since my right side doesn't work, I can't hear them. I want to set the sound so it only plays on the left side. I tried changing the balance settings in sound preferences, but it only mutes the right channel, doesn't make it play through the left channel. How can I do this?

Comment: You should look at making the sound mono. Apparently with stereo music the tracks can super impose and ruin the music. I'm not sure it's so bad but I think that's the track you want to go down.

Comment: Hm... I know iOS has this as an accessibility feature, but I don't see it under ubuntu universal access. This should definitely be added!
Voice your opinions here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/942780

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution at ubuntuforums.org, here's the link:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1384860&p=8689164

Basically you switch from pulseaudio to alsa, and you enable something called crosstalk, that allows you to hear both channels without 'super imposing' them.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/942780

> The mono profile is usually thrown away as most hardware does not
>   support opening it in one-channel mode only.
>
> You can configure pulseaudio to do what you suggest by modifying
>   /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/default.conf and
>   /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/extra-hdmi.conf
>
> In both files, go to the [Mapping analog-mono] section and change
>   channel-map = mono to channel-map = mono,mono
>
> This will take effect the next time pulseaudio is restarted (e g by
>   rebooting).
>
> The *major* question is however, whether we should do this by default,
>   and if we risk regressing other hardware by doing so.

-- David Henningsson (diwic)

Comment: I tried this approach, but I couldn't find an `extra-hdmi.conf` file (it no longer seems to exist), and when I just modified default.conf as described it broke my sound completely.  YMMV.