# Playing different music at different channels

Tags: sound

How to play one music in right channel, another music in left channel of laptop speaker/headphone simultaneously in Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pavucontrol` to achieve this. Simply start two applications which are capable of play music and than inside pavucontrol click on the lock to control the left and right channel. Mute the left channel for the first application and the right for the second application and you are done.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But I don't want to mute one channel. I need to play 2 channel data into one channel (right or left). Like that i want to play 1 song in left  channel and another song in right channel.

Comment: Could you update your question to make more clear what you are acutally trying to achieve? With terms like input/ouput/execpted behaviour. Because now i guess: Input: 2 audio files, audio output: 1 song (with both channels) played by left channel, 1 song (....) played by the right channel?

Comment: If this is true you could use my answer with the approach from [How to merge both audio channels into left channel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186236/how-to-merge-both-audio-channels-into-left-channel)
If you confirm the basic idea solves your problem, I can try to make a complete answer (updating my current own)

Comment: Yes you are right . I Expected the same question.